# Blazor component, null reference Error on page reload, but varible not null

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side

Get null reference when page reload.

In "if" statement no error but in "foreach" get exception

```
<div class="price-table">
@if (Offers != null && Offers.Any())
{
    @foreach (var offer in Offers))
    {
```

[image]

-Update full code listing  - Here full code listing with out utility methods.

```
<div class="price-table">
@if (Offers != null && Offers.Any())
{
    @foreach (var offer in Offers.Where(obj => obj != null))
    {
        <div class="price-table__row
            @(customer.Type == "retail" ?"":"price-row-club")
            @CheckOfferInBasketForRow(offer)">

            @if (customer.Type == "retail")
            {
                <div class="price-table__prices">
                    <!-- розничная цена -->
                    <div class="price price--rozn" id="prize-rozn">
                        <div class="price__sum">@offer.RetailPrice</div>
                        <div class="price__label">Розн. цена</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            }                
    }
}
```

```
@code {    
[Parameter] public ProductShortCard Product { get; set; }   
List<RetailOffer> Offers = new();
protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
{
    Offers = await _offerCase.GetRetailOfferListAsync(Product.DisProductId);
    customer = _customerContainr.Value;
}
```

}

Comment: [Polite]  This doesn't make sense, so I'm guessing there's something your not showing us.

Comment: add code listing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error was inside of foreach statement, and  in another variable.
found it by cuting part by part